# Classic ASP script first run different to subsequent runs

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, asp-classic

Apologises if the following sounds vague, but I'm stumped as to the reason.

My setup is classic ASP pages connecting to several SQL Server 2008 DBs with the exact same schema but different data in them.

My problem is that when I run my ASP script to create a report of the data in a database (simple queries with a bit of vbscript to add up certain stuff, concat a bit more string info, etc - the script runs and finishes in about 5 secs) the first execution of this script generates completely different data to when I run it a second, third, fourth, etc time and I have no idea why.

If I then run this same script on a different DB it gives me inaccurate data on the first run, but when I refresh the page the data returned is more to what I expect and will continue to do so.

I've looked at the code I just can't understand why the first run would be different to subsequent ones when nothing changes!

Any ideas?

Comment: If you could provide a [mcve] then this question would be answerable.

Comment: Hi Zohar, thank you for the quick response.  My problem is that the script file is 4077 lines long and I don't know where the problem area is.  If I could just figure out why the first run is always wrong and keep the problem there for subsequent runs then I might be able to isolate it.  At the moment I'm having to cycle through the DBs to keep creating the first run error

Comment: Try and give a condensed example, I have a vbscript array of people ids and as I loop through these ids I'm fetching their specific info back in a 2nd query.  Although the 2nd query will always bring back 7 rows per person I don't have an order by on it.  Is it possible that the first run brings back the rows in a diff order and then subsequent ones bring back in a more logical order - or a fluke to give it a better term?

Comment: A query without an order by clause might return the records in different order each time it runs (though that's usually not the case). If the order of the results matter, you must use the order by clause.

Comment: Zohar, you've got it!  Many thanks.  I'm getting a consistent run every time I do it now.  Thank you!

Comment: Glad to help :-) Feel free to answer your own question or delete it entirely.